# Need Help writing a function that accepts an array and an element, and returns an array with all occurrences of element removed

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is what I have tried, it always returns an array with only one value which is the element. I am also not sure if .splice is the correct way to remove the element from the array. Maybe I need a new array and .push only the items i want into it?

```
function remove(array, element) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (array[i] === element) {
            array = array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: Why not just use `array.filter(function(a){return a !== element;})`? There’s also a [polyfill for `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out there.

Comment: `array.splice` will modify `array` itself; what it returns is another array containing the removed item. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) also, it can be a bit dangerous to modify the size of a data structure in flight as you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to remove all instances of the element within the array.

```
   function remove(array, element) {

      var index = array.indexOf(element)
      array.splice(index,1)

      if (array.indexOf(element) > -1){
        return remove(array,element)
      }

      return array;
    }
```